# ASP.NET visual basic undefined functions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm converting a bunch of foxweb programs to asp.net.  Some of the functions I invoke in the asp code use "external functions," by which I mean functions that I have defined in .vb files.  For example, FileExists() is a nice function I would like to pull out into a common thing called clsCommon.vb .

I have implemented it like this:

```
Option Explicit On 
Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.Page

Public Class clsCommon
    Inherits Page

    Public Shared Function FileExists(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean
        If Dir$(filename) <> "" Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

I have tried using both DIR$() and DIR(). In each case, the error returned on the web page reads:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'Dir' is not declared.

As with other functions I have written I invoke FileExists() something like this:

```
<%@ page  Debug="true" inherits="clsCommon" src="clsCommon.vb" %>
<%

Dim filename as String = "example.txt"

If clsCommon.FileExists(filename) then
  Response.Write(filename & " Exists")
else
  Response.Write(filename & " does not Exist")
end if

%>
```

Note 1: While I want to solve this specific problem, what I'm really looking for is the general way to get to these functions like DIR(), CHR(), etc., that I have come to rely on in VB.

Note 2: asp seems to only look at the vb text file - and not at the compiled dll file, so I don't think the references I use have any effect on it.

Anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: You should call the built-in `File.Exists` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TheGeekYouNeed is certainly right.  The best approach is to either keep your code in VB (if it ain't broke, don't fix it) or consider investing some time in learning .Net

I have seen code conversion tools for turning VB code into VB.Net.  I can't imagine them working for non-trivial projects though.  Likewise, you can go out of your way to keep your code as 'VB like' as possible, but I think it's like burning down your house to avoid having to sweep the floor.

Anyway, the DIR function does still exist in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.71).aspx

The more generally accepted way of doing this in .NET would be to use `File.Exists`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Comment: File.Exists works so long as I add the line: Imports System.IO to the imports section of the vb code.

Comment: Additionally, to use the CHR() function, I need to add the line: Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Answer (score 1):

You are using VB.Net ... not VB.  There are differences, and you need to use the .Net framework appropriately.

Programming is always a lesson of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Figure out what function / method I need & search for it on msdn
When I find the function as in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr.aspx
There will be a line that says, for example,

**Namespace:**  Microsoft.VisualBasic

Use that name with an "Imports" near the beginning of the VB file, before the class definition as follows:

```
Option Explicit On 
Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.Page

' The two critical lines follow:
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class clsCommon
    Inherits Page

    Public Shared Sub TestExistence(ByVal filename As String)
        if NOT File.Exists(filename) then
            ' ... do something.
        end if
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function TestCHR(ByVal str As String) as string
        return str & chr(13) & chr(10)  'just an example
    End Function

End Class
```

MicroSoft.VisualBasic was required by the CHR() function
and System.IO was required by the File.Exists() function.

Comment: Imports isn't really needed.  It's nice to have.  Without it, you can still call the same functions as long as you fully qualify the namespace.